# extjs getting data from django rest api

Tags: django, rest, api, extjs

I'm trying to get data from a django rest api using Extjs. My Data represents a Tree which have a one-to-one relation to itself. I have this model:

```
Ext.define('mypackages.model.MyData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'myid',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string',
            mapping: 'name'
        },
        {
            name: 'family_name',
            type: 'string',
            mapping: 'family_name'
        }
    ]
});
```

And this is my store:

```
Ext.define('mypackages.store.MyData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    alias: 'store.files',
    model: 'mypackages.model.MyData',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: "rest",
        url: "/myurl/",
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'GET'
        },
        extraParamas:{
            'myid': ''
        }
    },
    constructor: function (config) {
        config = Ext.apply({
            root: Ext.clone(this.rootData)
        }, config);

        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

The api is working as expected, but, when I ran this and I went into the network inspector of my browser I can see a 404 due to this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl/root/?_dc=1553095552422`

How can I remove the `root/?_dc=1553095552422` from the request url, or what am I missing here in order to get this sending the correct request url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Remove the url attribute inside your proxy object;

2 - Change type: "rest" to type: "ajax";

3 - add an api attribute inside the proxy object like this:

```
api: {
            read: 'GETURL',
            create: 'POSTURL',
            update: 'PUTURL',
            destroy: 'DELETEURL'
        }
```

Comment: Change type: "rest" to type: "ajax". Which version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: Nice! I edited the question with this information so that you can accept it as the answer.